# Can't install R with sudo apt-get install r-base

Tags: r

When I try to install R with `sudo apt-get install r-base`, it says

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.  
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.2.1-4vivid0) but it is not going        
to be installed
      Depends: r-recommended (= 3.2.1-4vivid0) but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: [edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy r-base` and `apt-cache policy r-base-core`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, to fix it use

> http://< my.favorite.cran.mirror>/bin/linux/**ubuntu trusty**/

in the source list.

Comment: after updating your apt sources you need to do a `sudo apt-get update` followed by a `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have packages on hold. This command should upgrade your `R` bringing the new dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade --with-new-pkgs
```